# How Do I convert LinearGradientBrush object to a Style?

Tags: wpf, styles, fill, lineargradientbrush

What is the XAML Style equivalent of

```
LinearGradientBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 154, 153, 153), Color.FromArgb(255, 51, 50, 50), 80)
```

Ideally, I would like to make an Application Resource that I could reuse.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this Xaml...

```
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyDefaultBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#ff9a9999"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#ff333232"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

This sets a resource called "MyDefaultBackground" for the colours you gave in your question.  The start/stop values create a gradient where it's light grey at the top and dark grey at the bottom.  You can adjust the start/stop values for a different effect.

The color stop values are in hex (i.e., 153 decimal is 9a hex), when you need to translate decimal values, you can use the built-in windows calculator in 'programmer mode'.

Anytime you want to use it where the Style calls for a Brush, you can compose...

```
Background={StaticResource MyDefaultBrush}
```

This will work when the brush is declared higher in the object graph than the style you are composing.

The MSDN docs for LinearGradientBrush are at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)